# java string with extended ascii codes to byte arrary (allocate one byte per code)

Tags: java, c++, c, sockets

I have a java nio socket server that needs to communicate with a C socket client. The C socket client sends data to the server with ASCII codes above 127, using one byte per ASCII code. The server needs to send back the same.

I need to convert a string into a byte array with the same length (one byte per code).
The string is like `1200üö001001001`, where it contains some ascii codes above 127.
In the research I did, I did not find a solution. I tried this

```
byte[] b = "1200üö001001001".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] b = "1200üö001001001".getBytes("US-ASCII");
byte[] b = "1200üö001001001".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] b = "1200üö001001001".getBytes();
```

Some of these convert `üö` into `??` or multiple bytes per ASCII code, causing a different length between byte array and string.

I needing some help.

This is an example of data that comes from the C socket client. dots are ascii codes from Client.

```
<code>
0000 00 ff 31 32 30 30 fc f6 00 01 08 e1 e0 00 00 00 ..1200..........
0010 00 00 14 00 00 00 31 36 34 36 30 30 32 38 30 30 ......1646002800
0020 30 30 30 30 30 34 31 38 30 31 32 30 30 30 30 30 0000041801200000
0030 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 0000001000000000
0040 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 0010000000000010
0050 30 30 36 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 36 31 30 30 30 30 0061000000610000
0060 30 30 35 31 35 39 31 31 31 34 30 39 32 33 31 33 0051591114092313
0070 32 31 31 32 33 32 30 35 31 34 30 39 32 33 30 36 2112320514092306
0080 39 39 39 39 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 35 35 31 35 39 9999990000055159
0090 31 31 33 32 39 38 20 20 20 20 33 38 38 33 33 38 113298    388338
00a0 38 33 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 42 41 43 20 50 41 4e 83       XXX PAN
00b0 41 4d 41 20 54 45 53 54 3e 48 4f 57 41 52 44 20 AMA TEST>HOWARD
00c0 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 50                P
00d0 41 30 32 33 30 30 31 30 30 31 31 30 30 32 30 30 A023001001100200
00e0 33 37 30 30 30 32 35 30 30 31 31 38 34 30 38 34 3700025001184084
00f0 30 38 34 30 30 30 30 39 31 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 0840000911000000
0100 31
```

```
This is the code i use to convert from hex string to byte array

line 4 i convert from binary eg. 1101 to equvalent hex string eg `3F`
line 13 i take the bitmap in hex string eg. `"fcf6000108e1e0000000000014000000"`
        that contains 32 chars and try to convert to 16 bytes, but this results in 20 bytes
        because some chars takes more than one byte


       1     // Set bitmaps
       2     if ( String.copyValueOf(zeros).indexOf("1", 64) == -1 ) { zeros[0] = '0'; }
       3     tmp = String.copyValueOf(zeros);
       4     bits = binToHex(tmp);
       5
       6     // check bits to send
       7     if ( zeros[0] == '0') {
       8             bits = bits.substring(0, 16);
       9     }
      10
      11      // join message
      12      tmp = sb.toString();
      13      trm = isoCode + hexToASCII(bits) + tmp.substring(39);
      14      System.out.println("Trama respuesta " + (new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime())).toString() + " " + trm);

// here the code to send back the message from nio socet to client
   line mark with 100 add 2 space because there is a header with a short value that have the length of
   the message to be readed by socket client

            byte[] bytes = message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            writeLength = message.length();
            //writeLength = bytes.length;
       100  writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(writeLength + 2);
            writeBuffer.putShort( (short)writeLength );
            writeBuffer.put(message.getBytes());   // Para test
            //this.writeBuffer.putChar('\n');
            writeBuffer.flip();
```

// auxiliar methods

```
    public  String hexToASCII(String hex){

              if(hex.length()%2 != 0){

                 System.err.println("requires EVEN number of chars");
                 return null;
              }
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              //Convert Hex 0232343536AB into two characters stream.
              for( int i=0; i < hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
                   /*
                    * Grab the hex in pairs
                    */
                  String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
                  /*
                   * Convert Hex to Decimal
                   */
                  int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
                  sb.append((char)decimal);
              }
              return sb.toString();
        }

private final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private final String HEX[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
private final String BIN[] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

  /*
   *  Convert binary to hex string
   */
      public String binToHex(String bin) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length()-1 ; i += 4) {
            sb.append(HEX[ArrayUtils.indexOf(BIN, bin.substring(i, (i + 4)))]);
        } 
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I think you're flailing.  The data above is mixed binary and ASCII, and unless you know which is which you're sunk.  I don't think that the stuff up through byte 0x15 is intended to be character data.

Comment: Hot licks this is a ISO 8583 1993 message. The two first bytes is a short which contain the length of followin message. the next 4 bytes are the message code, next 16 bytes are a bitmap (in ascii codes) the rest of byes are the message.  the bitmap part is where i'm having the problem onverting it in bytes.

Comment: Ah, the Y of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) begins to emerge. Try asking "How to receive an ISO 8583:1993 message using Java NIO sockets?" and showing the code you are starting with.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing bytes and characters. There are dozens of ways to encode characters like ü and ö into bytes and different encodings take different amount of bytes per character.

DO NOT try to convert binary stream to string unless you know that the bytes represent textual information AND you know which encoding was used to convert the text into bytes in the first place. If the data is not a text string, DO NOT try to interpret it as a text string and just wish that every byte maps to something reasonable.

You can work directly with byte arrays or use e.g. `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. If there is a text string amongst the data, you can separately convert the peticular bytes into strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your binary bitmap is getting mangled by character encoding conversions. There is no point in doing it that way. You can just convert from hex to byte[].

This code suggests the way:

```
String bitmapHex = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"; 
String isoCode = "1200";
String data = "313030303030303031 and more";

byte[] bitmap = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(bitmapHex);

int datagramLength = 2 + isoCode.length() + bitmap.length + data.length();

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(datagramLength);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putShort((short)datagramLength);
buffer.put(isoCode.getBytes(encodingName));
buffer.put(bitmap);
buffer.put(data.getBytes(encodingName));

byte[] output = buffer.array();
```